# iptables moving from filter table back to nat table

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

in IPTABLES I believe that NAT table only looks at the first packet. This means that I cannot match for a string within the packet. I have to be in the filter table to match a packet based on the string.

So, if I want to match on a string for say 'redtube' I would like to able send this back to the NAT table to then do a DNAT.

EG:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 192.168.1.156 -m string --string 'redtube' --algo bm -J DROP
```

This command will drop any packets that contain redtube.

Is there any way to then send that connection back through nat so that I can use the -J DNAT target and send it off to another webserver that displays a block page?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "personalized" chain, and send the packet to that chain with "-j chain_name"

and than declare what to do in that chain so, for example

```
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 113 -m state --state NEW -j reject_func
```

and than

```
-A reject_func -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A reject_func -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A reject_func -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
```

Note the chain name in the 1st row "reject_func". It means "send it to that chain", and than, in the specified chain, he found where to go and what to do

(That's how SuSEFirewall2 works)

Comment: so this will help to block the packets but unfortunately I dont think it helps me to redirect the packets to another web server. This is ultimately what I want to do with these packets. Server up another webpage.